# What is the procedure to use Coursera's API to get users enrollments

Tags: api, coursera-api

Is any API available to get users enrollments from Coursera. After googling found that there is an API https://api.coursera.org/api/users/v1/me/enrollments, but no documentation found on this about the authentication and authorization process to invoke this API. Can anyone suggest how to do OAuth in Coursera

Comment: After exploring the courser API , I could find  the process of OAuth. First we need to Auth using URI https://accounts.coursera.org/oauth2/v1/auth?response_type=code&client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI]&scope=view_profile&state=csrf_code1234. It redirects to coursera login screen after authentication it returns the CODE. But I am facing trouble in making enrollment API by passing the CODe which was returned after successful Auth, The enrollments API says "Invalid Code". Could anyone help in this regard

Comment: Could anyone help to answer this question